# Reposted from GitHub: Spring Boot Application fails to start with error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring-boot

Please note: This is an issue moved from GitHub
**Spring Boot Application fails to start: Reports an error "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Object;)V**

**I am trying to add a dependency(using older spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE) to  spring new boot application that I am trying to build using 2.0.3.RELEASE.

Before the dependency is added, the new spring Boot application works fine, but once I add the dependency, the application fails to run, although the compilation works seamlessly. The dependency has critical business logic that needs to be used, rather than re-coding the entire thing.
Any idea, someone had faced a similar issue? Would be great to find help...

Trying to understand, if its issue with incompatible versions, or is it something silly that I am missing.

Following is the error that I get..**

```
20:10:54.966 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at au.com.vish.ai.conversation.BillApplicationBoot.main(BillApplicationBoot.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext (BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent (BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent (BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared (EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared (SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment (SpringApplication.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:317)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at au.com.vish.ai.conversation.yaagent.BillApplicationBoot.main (BillApplicationBoot.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

**The POM file has the following as part of dependencies.**

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
                <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- The below internal dependency coded in SpringBoot 1.5.10-RELEASE when added causes the issue. When commented, works like fine-->
             <dependency>
                <groupId>au.com.server.viewpaybills</groupId>
                <artifactId>viewbills-common</artifactId>
                <version>0.3.35.CB</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: A solution available is as provided in  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14200#issuecomment-415966020,  by Spencer

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions in a single post. If you've resolved the issue using an existing fix that you discovered after posting, then delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have added spring cloud dependency  Finchley.SR1 POM, that helped resolve the issue. 
However following that and running the application, throws an exception "InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate'".
Although I have not been using Redis in my Spring Boot application.
On checking the maven dependency tree, I could find redis to be in the classpath,
due to the dependencies added in my POM. Trying to figure out how to overcome this issue now.

Following is the exception that I get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method redisTemplate in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'redisConnectionFactory' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'redis.clients.jedis.Jedis'
    - Bean method 'redisConnectionFactory' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.lettuce.core.RedisClient'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' in your configuration.

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray (ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization (AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at au.com.vish.ai.conversation.yaagent.BillApplicationBoot.main (BillApplicationBoot.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument (ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray (ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization (AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at au.com.vish.ai.conversation.yaagent.BillApplicationBoot.main (BillApplicationBoot.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.508 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-27T00:05:55+10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 65M/735M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project dialogflow-agent-api: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {} -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get more info on the startup error include the dependency found here `https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/19/spring-cloud-finchley-release-is-available`

Just including the POM dependency was sufficient for more details to appear int he logs.